# Get control name in Button event handler method Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I have 20 buttons in my Xamarin Forms app . All of the buttons share the same click event method. What I want to do is use switch statement to check the button name but I am having difficulty finding the controls name that fired the event .

Please see the code :

```
private  void btnCollection_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var btn = (Button)sender;

        switch (btn.FindByName) // I want to get the name of the control 
        {

            case "btn1":
                break;

                case "btn2":
                break;
        }
    }
```

How can I get the button's name?

Comment: btn.Name should work... Your btn reference shows to your Button so you can directly request the name from it.

Comment: There is no Name property in xamarin forms buttons !

Answer (score 37):

You cannot access the x:Name property of a xaml element as this is just a hint for the compiler to name the variable.

What you can do however is to set the `ClassId` of your button so that you can retrieve it in the handler. Like this:
Your xaml :

```
<Button ClassId="sdsd"
              Clicked="Button_OnClicked"/>
```

Your xaml.cs

```
private void LoginButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var button = (Button) sender;
            var classId = button.ClassId;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel . It works .Sorry I can't vote for the answer you gave because I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: This solves the issue but as per Microsoft at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.Element.ClassId?view=xamarin-forms), this it not `ClassId`'s purpose. I too am stuck at this point (new to Xamarin). So in need of a real solution. I exactly have the same problem, want to identify the button uniquely.

Comment: You can create a class that inherits from Button in which you have whatever you want and set it from xaml

Answer (score 11):

Maybe this can help you

```
if(sender is Button){

   Button button = (Button)sender;
   if(button.Equals(myButton1)){
      // You are in myButton1
   }else if(button.Equals(myButton2)){
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var btn = (Button)sender;

if(btn.Id == btn1.Id) {

}
else if(btn.Id == btn2.Id){
}
```

Comment: Please add a little explain about how this fix is solving the issue or, what was the incorrect part in the code posted in the question.

Comment: And what is `_Rubrica`?

Comment: Pardon .. it's an xaml button :
<Button 
                x:Name="_Rubrica"

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure @abdul is far past this now, but `ClassId` should be used to identify a type of button.

I would expect each button to have a unique text field, though:

```
<Button Text="My awesome button" Clicked="MyAwesomeClickHandler"/>
```

Which may be easily read in the event handler method:

```
private void MyAwesomeClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Button myAwesomeButton= (Button) sender;
     string myAwesomeText= myAwesomeButton.Text;
}
```

This is how most people I know do it, so I thought it might help.